# How do I make ngFor with input inside not repeat the typing value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I need to make multiple inputs with ngFor but when I enter a word, it is repeated in all the inputs there are, how can I solve this?

[image]

**my code:**

```html
    <div class="" *ngFor="let publication of publications">
            ...
        <form #newCommentForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newCommentForm, $event, publication._id)">
           <div class="make-comment" >
              <img src="{{url+ 'get-image-user/' + publication.user.image }}" *ngIf="publication.user.image" class="rounded-circle-mini align-self-center">              
              <input type="text" name="#text" #text="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="comment.text" id="input-coment" class="form-control" required placeholder="Your comment">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="color: #fff;" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left"></i></button>    
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the variable 'comment.text' to every input [model]. Meaning, its value is shared between all your input scopes. You need to use 'publication', which is only scoped to each input.

```
*ngFor="let publication of publications"
```

Change `[(ngModel)]="comment.text"` to something like `[(ngModel)]="publication.text"`

Comment: "comment" is a table of which one of its attributes is "text", the value that I input must be stored there. Making the change you say doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding all inputs to a single property `comment.text`. You should create one property for each input and bind input with it.

Comment: The problem is not the data entry (the form works fine, each "comment" is made in the "publication" that I want). The problem is at the time of writing the comment, which each typing is reflected in all the inputs.

Comment: @AdrielSilvestre if that's true, please update your question to include the actual code because this is the answer given the question you submitted

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry if the question was not understood, I will try to write it better

Comment: The thing is, I do think you're doing exactly what @NenadMilosavljevic says you are. You haven't introduced a loop scoped variable named `comment` meaning that your binding to a member in the scope outside the iterator